# How do I stop an empty tag from being emitted by XmlSerializer?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have an object like this,

```
public class UserObj
{
    public string First {get; set;}
    public string Last  {get; set;}
    public addr Address {get; set;}

}

public class addr
{
    public street {get; set;}
    public town   {get; set;}
}
```

Now when I use XmlSerializer on it and street and town are empty I get this in the XML output,

```
 <Address />
```

Is there a way not to output this empty tag?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to avoid empty tags ? They are valid XML, aren't they ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may implement [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) and implement the serialization routine on your own. This way, you can avoid the element.

An example here: http://paltman.com/2006/jul/03/ixmlserializable-a-persistable-example/

Answer (score 6):

You can implement a `ShouldSerializeAddress` method to decide whether or not the Address property should be serialized :

```
public bool ShouldSerializeAddress()
{
    return Address != null
        && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Address.street)
        && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Address.town);
}
```

If the method exists with this signature, the serializer will call it before serializing the property.

Alternatively, you can implement an `AddressSpecified` property which has the same role :

```
public bool AddressSpecified
{
    get
    {
        return Address != null
            && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Address.street)
            && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Address.town);
    }
}
```

Comment: For the second, `xxxSpecified`, solution, the `AddressSpecified` property must be marked with `[XmlIgnore]` to prevent it from being serialized also, as mentioned in [MinOccurs Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c.aspx#Translating%20XSD%20to%20source)

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the empty value by adding a DefaultValue attribute to the property.  When the value of the property matches the default value, it isn't serialized.  You set the default value to null, to eliminate the serialization.  Here's an example:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
public class UserObj
{
    public string First {get; set;}
    public string Last  {get; set;}

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public addr Address {get; set;}

}
```

Comment: This did not work for me, but @Thomas-Levesque's answer did.

Answer (score 0):

I think assigning null value to address field should work.