# C# Object Serialization to XML with ignoring null element

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

```
[XmlRoot("SAPInformationInterchangeXML")]
public class EWayBillResponseXML
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SAPBusinessNetworkCustomerID")]
    public string SAPBusinessNetworkCustomerID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "INVOIC")]
    public ResponseINVOIC Invoice { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseINVOIC
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "HeaderInformation")]
    public string HeaderInformation { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AuthorizationInformation")]
    public string AuthorizationInformation { get; set; }
}


    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true,
        OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
        Encoding = encoding
    };

    string requestHeaderInformation = null, requestAuthorizationInformation = null;

    EWayBillResponseXML obj = new EWayBillResponseXML
                    {
                        SAPBusinessNetworkCustomerID = "1",
                        Invoice = new ResponseINVOIC
                        {
                            HeaderInformation = requestHeaderInformation,
                            AuthorizationInformation = requestAuthorizationInformation
                        }
    };

    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
        {
            x.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(stream.ToArray()));
    }
```

I have created 2 objects named EWayBillResponseXML and ResponseINVOIC. I tried to serialize using above code snippet. It gives me serialized XML but it returns null object element too. I don't need null object in serialized XML. Can you Please help me out.

Currently getting output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<SAPInformationInterchangeXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SAPBusinessNetworkCustomerID>1</SAPBusinessNetworkCustomerID>
<INVOIC />
</SAPInformationInterchangeXML>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<SAPInformationInterchangeXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SAPBusinessNetworkCustomerID>1</SAPBusinessNetworkCustomerID>
</SAPInformationInterchangeXML>
```

Comment: `<INVOIC />` isn't a null element.  A null element would look like `<INVOIC xsi:nil="true" />`.  Instead, it's an [*empty element*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-empty).  It is emitted because the property `Invoice` is non-null and allocated, however all of its members are null so no child elements are created.  If you want to prevent empty elements from being emitted for non-null members, see [How do I stop and empty tag in XML serializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2958151/3744182).  In fact this may be a duplicate.  Agree?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following method to your serializable class (`EWayBillResponseXML`):

```
        public bool ShouldSerializeInvoice()
        {
            return Invoice != null;
        }
```

You can [read more about that here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/defining-default-values-with-the-shouldserialize-and-reset-methods).

Comment: above snippet not working

Comment: It works for me. I use this extensively in production code that I wrote a year or two ago. Not to mention, you can see the example of this on Microsoft's site. Did you put it in the same class as the property is declared? How are you using it, and what is "not working" about it?

Comment: This does not solve @Ronak's problem because, in their code, `Invoice` is actually non-null.  All its members are null, however, which is why an empty element is emitted for it.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/MKmfDL

Answer (score 0):

As @gmiley said, you should make method named like this `ShouldSerialize___` where `___` is the name of property that should or not be serialized. That method needs to be in class where is said property

So, in your case, make `ShouldSerializeResponseINVOIC` method in your `EWayBillResponseXML` class

```
[XmlRoot("SAPInformationInterchangeXML")]
public class EWayBillResponseXML
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SAPBusinessNetworkCustomerID")]
    public string SAPBusinessNetworkCustomerID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "INVOIC")]
    public ResponseINVOIC Invoice { get; set; }

    public book ShouldSerializeInvoice()
    {
        return Invoice != null;
    }

}
```

Edit:
Dbc correctly said in comment that Invoice is not actually null but empty, so you should handle that.

Comment: This does not solve @Ronak's problem because, in their code, `Invoice` is actually non-null.  All its members are null, however, which is why an empty element is emitted for it.  Furthermore, in any `ShouldSerializeXXX()` method the name `XXX` must match the property name, here `Invoice`.  In your code you are using the name of the returned type `ResponseINVOIC` which is not correct.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/A20c5A

Comment: You are right in both cases. I saw you comment on question and saw that you're right. At least I'll fix the code to actually compiles and returns if property should be serialized :)