# How do I stop an empty tag of a collection from being emitted by XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, serialization, collections

Whilst searching for an advice, I came across various solutions: from [IXMLSerializer](http://paltman.com/ixmlserializable-a-persistable-example) via [ShouldSerialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958151/how-do-i-stop-an-empty-tag-from-being-emitted-by-xmlserializer) and up to a simple .Replace() or RegEx.
I don't want to use the latter two, as I think they are inefficient, but I don't have enough C# knowledge to implement Serializer related suggestions in my case, so hope one can advise, please.

I have "Details" collection of various travel related options - flight, train, hotel etc... The XSD class has been provided to us by a 3rd party and below is the relevant part:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Details")]
public class Details
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Flight")]
    public Flight Flight { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Train")]
    public Train train { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RentalCar")]
    public RentalCar rentalCar { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Hotel")]
    public Hotels Hotel { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Bus")]
    public Bus Bus { get; set; }

}
```

Each of the elements has its own XMLRoot, e.g. Hotel one:

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Hotel")]
    public class Hotels
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "VoucherNo")]
        public string VoucherNo { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "VoucherRef")]
        public string VoucherRef { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DepartureDate")]
        public string departureDate;
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DepartureDateFieldSpecified")]
        public bool departureDateFieldSpecified;
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReturnDate")]
        public string returnDate;
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReturnDateFieldSpecified")]
        public bool returnDateFieldSpecified;
    }
```

Details in turn is a part of Product

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Product")]
public class Product
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ArticleNumber")]
    public int articleNumber { get; set; }
//many other elements
    public Details Details { get; set; }

}
```

In my code I declare objProductDetails collection

```
Details objProductDetails = new Details();
```

and populate with the relevant data. some of the elements can remain empty: not every travel has a train or a rented car, so for example I can have only Hotel element populated. I use not null check as below

```
if (objHotel != null)
      objProductDetails.Hotel = objHotel;

if (objRentalCar != null)
      objProductDetails.rentalCar = objRentalCar;
```

Currently, when I execute my code, I do get all the data for the hotel, but an empty tag for everything else :

Hotel:

```
<qfl:Product>
  <qfl:ArticleNumber>100</qfl:ArticleNumber>
     <qfl:Details>
        <qfl:Hotel>
          <qfl:VoucherNo>1234</qfl:VoucherNo>

/...... rest of the result
```

else

```
 <qfl:Product>
    <qfl:ArticleNumber>180</qfl:ArticleNumber>
       <qfl:Details />
  </qfl:Product>
        /...... rest of the result
```

What would be the best way to skip the empty Details element, to recieve the following please:

```
 <qfl:Product>
     <qfl:ArticleNumber>180</qfl:ArticleNumber>
 </qfl:Product>
```

N.B. Following Ivan's comments below, I have seem to have another issue - although my rent a car object is empty, objRentalCar == null is false. Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create empty `Details` object accordingly it is serialized as empty tag. If you don't want serialize it you should check that all properties in this object would be empty and don't create object or don't set property `Details` in `Product` object.

```
if (objHotel != null || objRentalCar != null || ...)
{
    product.Details = objProductDetails;
}
```

Comment: objHotel in my case is not null, hence your if() clause will return true and continue same as I have at the moment. Or I miss something?

Comment: Then Details property cannot be empty tag. It contains Hotel data. Or do you want not serialize Hotel data?

Comment: Seems the issue is with objRentalCar. I will try to attach an image, but although it shows me all its elements are null, objRentalCar !=null returns true. Can you advise why, please?

Comment: You have object with all properties are null. It is valid, you need not create such object. I mean check data before creation object and if all data are null, just not create the empty object.

Comment: yes, I have instantiated it `RentalCar objRentalCar = new RentalCar();` otherwhise it will fail with an exception.

Comment: Oh... To make it work I had to use `RentalCar objRentalCar = null` instead. Thank you for the help.